# Posible reason for drop in Honda Jazz mileage immediately after servicing?

Tags: mileage

My Honda Jazz (2012 model) was serviced recently. Car has completed 57,000 km, so service centre told me to get jobs done as per schedule for 60,000 km. Post service, the mileage dropped from 13 kpl to 9.5kpl. 
Jobs done in service- oil check, filters change, fuel injector cleaning, throttle body cleaning, exhaust cleaning, HDS scanning apart from usual service. What is the likely cause of drop in mileage?

Comment: Driver enjoying the extra power?

Comment: Perhaps they used a lot of fuel during servicing but didn't go anywhere.

Comment: I refueled to a full tank auto cut and reset the trip meter. Average is what I got in the 1 week after that.